# Set the same Label width for each EntryCell in Xamarin TableView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm learning how to use `<TableView>` in Xamarin Forms and I wrote this:

```
<TableView Intent="Form">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="Random values">
            <EntryCell Label="A beautiful first number" Placeholder="1" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <EntryCell Label="2nd num" Placeholder="2" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

How can I set the same width to each `<entry cell>`? I don't want the input parts to start in different horizontal positions.

Comment: use `WidthRequest`

Comment: @Jason <EntryCell>, <TableSection> and <TableRoot> don't have "WidthRequest", and if i use it in <TableView>, obviously It doesn't set the Label width.

Comment: interesting, I just assumed it did.  If you want that level of control you might need to use a ViewCell and build your own layout

Comment: I was hoping it was possible with simple <EntryCell>, but in this case... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge , [Custom Cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview#custom-cells) would be the good choice to achieve that . Because `Entry Cell` hasn't a propery to set `Width` of `Label` .

Using View Cell can contain Layout to fit your needs as follow :

```
<TableView Intent="Form" >
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="Random values">
            <EntryCell Label="A beautiful first number"
                        Placeholder="1 Entry Cell"
                        Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <EntryCell Label="2nd num"
                        Placeholder="2 Entry Cell"
                        Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Padding="2">
                    <Label Text="A beautiful first number"
                            WidthRequest="150" 
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <Entry Placeholder="1 View Cell" WidthRequest="250"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="2" >
                    <Label Text="2nd num"
                            WidthRequest="150"
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    <Entry Placeholder="2 View Cell" 
                            WidthRequest="250" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

The effect :

[image]